# How to mark question as resolved without accepting any particular answer

Tags: support, questions, close-reasons, accepted-answer

Is there a way to mark a question as resolved, without having to accept a particular answer?

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, and although I did not a receive a satisfactory answer, the issue has been resolved and I would like to close the question. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't, but you can post your own answer

Comment: @toolic The issue just went away. I was having an issue trying to create an Android virtual device in Android Studio, and on my 15th try, it just worked. I didn't change anything. I figure I might was well close the question because it was about a problem that was unique to my situation. I don't think this really affects anyone else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your problem was resolved because of something you did, write your own answer explaining what you did to fix it and accept that (you may have to wait before accepting it, depending on how long ago you asked your question).

If it just went away on its own and you have no idea why, then it probably won't provide any value to future readers. You can just delete it, or if you're unable to delete it (e.g. because of multiple/upvoted answers) then flag/close-vote it as "not reproducible" and leave a comment explaining that so people who can vote to close it will know what to do.

Comment: Can't the OP just close their own question?

Comment: @10Rep Not unilaterally, it still takes two more votes. Hence the comment.

Comment: @10Rep Only Mods have single-vote closure powers (Except dupe-hammers which can be wielded by the general public, but that's only one close reason). Post authors can vote to close their own question with the privilege, but it's not a binding vote alone.

Answer (score 8):

The only way to mark a question as "resolved" is to accept an answer. However, even then if someone comes along with a better answer they're more than welcome to post it.

In your situation I'd add your own answer detailing how you solved the problem - assuming that it is an answer to the question and accept that. This will indicate to future visitors that you're not still looking for a solution.